# Why does getRootInActiveWindow() return null when trying to get the SMS window

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I'm developing an application which reads the text on the screen to the user. When a user enters an SMS conversation, I want to read the messages sequentially from top to bottom.

To query the window which holds all of the UI elements (ie TextViews, EditTexts, etc.) of the SMS conversation, I am using `getRootInActiveWindow()` inside the `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)` method of my accessibility service. However, every time an `AccessibilityEvent` from the SMS window (package name: `com.google.android.apps.messaging`) is fired, `getRootInActiveWindow()` returns **null**.

Why does that occur and how can I get over this problem?

Thank you for the time taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `canRetrieveWindowContent` in `SERVICE_META_DATA` to `true`.

[Service Meta Data for Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#SERVICE_META_DATA)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off getting the window from the source of your event. getRootInActiveWindow() is a bit of a holdover from an earlier time, and there are moments when there isn't an active window and/or that window isn't registered or responding properly.

Comment: Okay; But then, say the UI contains several EditText instances. When one of the EditText instances is clicked, how can I get the root window of that EditText?

Comment: AccessibilityNodeInfos form a tree. You can traverse up to the root, or get the corresponding window and get its root node.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting `getRootInActiveWindow()` as null then try to get node inside of that particular node and then after that you can query `getRootInActiveWindow()` on that particular node.

Example:

```
node.getRootInActiveWindow() = null;
```

then try, `node.get(0).getRootInActiveWindow()` or `node.get(1).getRootInActiveWindow()`

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: I can't even call `node.getRootInActiveWindow()`, `getRootInActiveWindow()` can only be called separately